# JQuery click 1 does nothing

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

I have a feeling there is something wrong with my for loop. When my websites event is activated the first time, I get no response. It works as intended every time after that. I have tried tuning the numbers in the for loop looking for mistakes but as far as what I've tried. It works best as is.

For the full app: https://codepen.io/xcidis/full/KvKVZb/

```
var reference = [];

function random() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: "method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?",
      success: function(quote) {
        reference.push([quote.quoteText + "<br/><br/><br/><div align='right'>~" + quote.quoteAuthor + "</div>"]);
      }
  });
}

$("button").click(function(){
  random();
  for(i=0;i<4; i++){
    if(reference[reference.length-1] == undefined){continue}else{
    var boxes = $("<div id='boxes'></div>").html("<p>" + reference[reference.length-1] + "</p>");
  $('body').append(boxes);
      break;
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Worked first time for me.

Comment: It has to do with reference[0] being the first in line. If I run my ajax function random(); before my jquery it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rest of the code ran before your ajax push the value to reference variable.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

You can either put your page rendering code within the ajax or use some tips to run the rederer synchronously

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.when(  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: "method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?",
      success: function(quote) {
        reference.push([quote.quoteText + "<br/><br/><br/><div class='tweet' align='left'></div><div align='right'>~" + quote.quoteAuthor + "</div>"]);
      }
  })).then(function() {
      console.log(reference)
      for(i=0;i<4; i++){
        if(reference[reference.length-1] == undefined){continue}else{
        var boxes = $("<div id='boxes'></div>").html("<p>" + reference[reference.length-1] + "</p>");
      $('body').append(boxes);
          break;
        };
      };
    });    
  });
```